# how to push objects into an array rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord-import

I am using `gem 'activerecord-import'` for bulk import in rails application. I have some sample codes as follows:

```
articles = []

10000.times do |i| 
 articles << Article.new(:name => "Article #{i}") 
end 

Article.import articles
```

Here in the code,i am importing 10000 new records in couple of seconds.But if i am creating bulk of comments for an article like:

```
comments = []
@article= Article.find(1)
10000.times do |i| 
  comments << @article.comments.find_or_create_by(:name => "comment #{i}") 
end 

Comment.import comments
```

While running the above code, comments are get created in the loop **without being pushed in the array**.
How do i push all the comments into the array before creation.Please help me out.

Comment: Do you mean `@article << comments` ?

Comment: this line `comments << @article.comments.find_or_create_by(:name => "comment #{i}") `

Comment: Can you print `comments` after the loop? Is your code throwing any error?

Comment: @Udaykumardas Try `@article.comments.where(name: "comment #{i}").first_or_create`

Comment: are you sure the comments are __not__ in the array ? `find_or_create_by` would always return an object, no matter what ; my guess is that `import` simply ignores already persisted objects, or ignores errors on save. Use the debugger or the console to verify this.

Comment: no, comments are created in the loop which takes a longer time as compare `Article.import`. If i am able to use `Comment.import` then it will be helpfull.

Comment: your code looks fine, can u check whats the length of the array before the line `Comment.import comments` , like `p comments.length` ?